# set Activity dialog uncancelable

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-studio

I have an activity which i am using as a dialog in my app(by making use of `Theme.Dialog` and `startActivity(dialogactivityintent)`). But I don't want it to close when the user presses the back button (which all android phones have). I've searched a lot but couldn't find a solution to this.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've tried using `setCancelable(false)` but in vain.

Answer (score 5):

HI use the following code::

Paste this line next to setContentView(R.layout.main)

```
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

and disable the back Key using the following line:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Comment: This is correct answer. I should have been approved. It has worked fine in my case

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this method :

```
setCancelable(false).
```

Comment: I've tried using that but it show the error cannot resolve method.

Comment: The error is : Gradle: error: cannot find symbol method setCancelable(boolean)

Comment: can u paste ur Activty itself in pastie.org

Comment: No. I can't do so as I have a lot of components and code in it!

Comment: ok , u can see example here :http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDialogs/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you had used a dialog you should have used :

- setCanceledOnTouchOutside()
- setCancelable()

But, as you used an activity, just override onBackPressed and do nothing in it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Could you please give a sample code of what you suggested?

Comment: @Override public void onBackPressed() {}